# How does Terrarion work?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am a bit confused of the artifact card [Terrarion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerrarion%5d). Does this card allow me to gain 2 mana of any color forever when I tap 2 mana, tap Terrarion, and sacrifice it? Or do I only gain that mana for that turn?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between mana and lands?

Comment: This question isn't really about Terrarion, but rather the mana system. Abilities (such as tapping lands) add mana to your mana pool, where it floats around until you use it, or until the step/phase ends. Lands aren't mana - they just have the ability to tap to produce mana (generally once a turn). Mana never lasts forever unless something says otherwise - it drains if you don't use it quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What [Terrarion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTerrarion%5d) basically does, is repaint the color of mana. If you have two blue mana, but need a red and a green one, you can activate Terrarion's ability.

Let's look at that ability: The cost to activate it are on the left side of the `:`, and he effects on the right. The costs are: `pay 2 mana, tap Terrarion and sacrifice it`.

- The mana may be of any color, or even colorless
- Why bother tapping it if we're going to sacrifice it anyway? Terrarion comes into play tapped, and once it's tapped you can't tap it again. So, in the first turn you can't activate this ability.
- Sactifice it. This one's obvious. Note that Terrarion has a `leaves the battlefield` triggered ability, so you get to draw a card.

As for the effect: You can choose to add 2 mana of any color (though not colorless - Terrarion requires us to choose from the Colors of Magic: Red, Green, White, Black or Blue). They can be two different colors, or 2 mana of the same color, as per Gatherer:

> You can get either two mana of the same color or one mana each of different colors.

But didn't we just *pay* two mana. Yes, we've paid 2 mana of color XY, and gained 2 mana of color WZ. You have effectively repainted 2 mana to better suit your purposes.

Comment: The mana generated by Tarririon can not be colorless. Rule 105.4

Comment: @DrunkCynic thx, added specifically.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are confused between **lands** and **mana**. Lands are cards that (usually) *produce* mana; they are "permanents" so they stick around on the battlefield turn after turn. Mana is *always* a temporary resource (usually obtained by tapping a land, but also available from other sources like Terrarion) which you either spend to cast spells and such, or don't spend in which case it vanishes at the end of the current phase of the turn. There is no such thing as "gaining mana forever".